# Custom Attributes of array type

Tags: android, xml, custom-attributes

Can someone please help me on how can i define an custom attribute of type "string-array" because i cannot find Formats to define array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomWidget">
        <attr name="myarray" format="string-array"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This code doesn't seem to work.
What should be my "format"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using

```
    format="string-array"
```

I used

```
    format="reference"
```

and referred it to string-array resource.